# Why test loss fluctuates so much using Resnet?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

Here is a typical plot of train/test losses behaviour as epoch increases.
[image]

I'm not an expert but I have read several topics on similar problems. Well, let me explain what I'm doing.

First, I have used implementation given by https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py for resnet18 & resnet50,  and by https://github.com/akamaster/pytorch_resnet_cifar10 for resnet32, resnet56. For all these nets I got the same kind of test-loss hieratic behaviour.

Second, my inputs are images 5x64x64, so I have adapted the first Convolutional Layer, and the output of the last Full-connected consist of 180 neurons. I have used either 64, 128, 256 batch sizes for the training, and 128 for the test: the same behaviour persists. I have also both used 300k or 100k images in input training (100k for the test): same  behaviour persists too. The images are not of "standard" RGB photos: first, as you probably have already, ,  remarked there are 5 channels, second the pixel values can be negative (eg. spanning the range  (-0.01, 500))

Third, I am aware of the model.train() statement for the training phase, as well as the model.eval() statement (coupled with the  with torch.no_grad():) for the testing phase.  It is clear that if I do not use model.eval() during the test phase, the test loss is gently decrasing as the traing loss. But, this is not allowed, isn't it?

I have tried several things after reading post concerning Batch Norm behaviour wo any success

- I have used SGD, Adam (& SWATS)
- I have tryied lr = 0.1 to lr= 1e-5
- I have modified the BN momentum (default = 0.1) : 0.5 and 0.01; as well as the eps parameter.

Now, I have managed to get nice results (ie; good training & testing losses) with a classical CNN (ie. wo any Batch normalization, & short-cuts) but I would like to study  Resnet behaviour against adversarial attack. So, I would like to get Resnet fit my images :slight_smile:

Any idea ?
Thanks

After making some tests, I have found something: I have used the standard resnet20 (h=1). Then, I have used as test set the same samples (100,000 images) as for the train set. BUT, for the test set 1) I do not use the shuffling, and 2) I do not make any Horizontal/vertical flip or Rot90deg, Rot180deg or Rot270deg. **I observe the same kind of fluctuations for the test loss**.
[image]

Moreover, when I switch OFF complety the transformations of the train set, and uses the same set for train & test, I got the same behviour:
[image]

And finaly, if I switch off the suffling and random transforms (flips & Rotations) of train set, and I use the same set for test, then I get:
[image]

Seems that the test loss is converging towards a value, but different from the train loss. Why ???

Comment: This problem is currently an open area of research. Just doing a quick literature search, the paper [Towards Robust ResNet: A Small Step but a Giant Leap](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/0595.pdf) seems promising and is well written. It also has some code on [github](https://github.com/zjfheart/Robust-ResNet) although the code isn't too general so may require some work on your end.

Comment: Ho my god! great thanks @jodag I was not aware that I was playing with knowledge frontier . Diving into Zhang et al paper & github code, I think I have andstood how they have modified the Resnet BasicBlock. I will try it right know and let u know.

Comment: First result: resnet56 with h=0.1 (default=1) gives no improvments. I try h=0.01. Nb: h is the factor in out = h*out + shortcut(x).

Comment: resnet56 h=0.01: no improvments...

Comment: I have tried with resnet20, h=0.1,1,2   no improvment. :(

Comment: Yeah it's a tough problem which you may not be able to solve :/. If it were me I would probably just choose the best checkpoint and call it good.